# WiX waits for the launched process to complete installation

Tags: process, wix, windows-installer, custom-action, wix3.10

I am using the below lines to execute a process from an exe that is in the installed directory.

```
<SetProperty Id="LaunchMosquitto" Value="&quot;[#fil7D28AEF774656849395A2FA20A5C963D]&quot; -c [#filA995207A6EF3FF0B4A1912B4627C6A9E]" Before="LaunchMosquitto" Sequence="execute"/>
<CustomAction Id="LaunchMosquitto"
              BinaryKey="WixCA"
              DllEntry="WixQuietExec64"
              Return="ignore"
              Impersonate="no" />
```

I am using this approach to run the exe silently with arguments after the installation. But the installer is waiting for the spawned process to terminate for the installation to complete. Though the process is spawned, installer hangs there. It completes only when I close the spawned process. This is because of the Return=ignore property I believe. Perhaps async-no-wait would help. But that requires ExecCommand instead of the SetProperty. The problem in using that is it launches the command prompt after installation to spawn the process. Kind of caught in a dead lock here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Using the asyncNoWait in combination of start your process with no window\silently does not work? (If you are using WixQuietExec64 method that uses ProcessStartInfo class with the property CreateNoWindow  = true)

Comment: Since I'm using WixQuietExec64, I cannot use the asyncNoWait. Because asyncNoWait requires the presence of ExecCommand. ExecCommand cannot co-exist with DllEntry. Without DllEntry, you cannot have WixQuietExec64. That's the whole issue.

Comment: Oh sorry when I've tested it on my environment I've changes the wrong custom action, yeah it does not compile...